# Best way to share object between threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

I have a main `Swing` app with class members `BufferedImage lastCapturedImage`,  `ScheduledExecutorService executor` with 2 threads in the thread pool.

```
BufferedImage lastCapturedImage;
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
...
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(imageCaptureRunnable, 100, 1000 / TARGET_FPS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
executor.schedule(roboticArmRunnable, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The first `Runnable` pulls images (`BufferedImage`) from a webcam and updates a class instance `lastCapturedImage`.

```
private final Runnable imageCaptureRunnable = new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    lastCapturedImage = webcam.getImage();
  }

};
```

The second `Runnable` processes the image and controls a robotic arm. The image capturing rate is much faster than the robotic arm consumer and only the most current image is needed by the robotic arm consumer. How best do I share the image in a thread safe way?

After researching this topic, my solution is to wrap the image (`lastCapturedImage`) in a `synchronized` block in the `roboticArmRunnable`'s `run()` method, and make a copy of the image like this:

```
private final Runnable roboticArmRunnable = new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(true){
      BufferedImage clonedCameraCapture;
      synchronized (lastCapturedImage) {
        clonedCameraCapture = copyImage(lastCapturedImage);
      }
      // process the clonedCameraCapture image and move the robotic arm
    }
  }
};
```

My understanding is that the `synchronized` block will allow for the `roboticArmRunnable` to completely make the copy of the image before the `imageCaptureRunnable` is allowed to update the image. Am I doing this right??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a threadsafe queue (either a threadsafe impl or justn synchronize on it) for the images, i.e. the producer pushes images to the queue and the consumer pops them again. That way you'd not have to copy the images around.

Comment: There is no way to know if you're doing it right with so few code. We need to see how the two runnables read and modify the image. For example, we don't even know if you replace the old image by a new one, or if you modify its state. Post all the relevant code.

Comment: @JBNizet I added the relevant code.

Comment: This sounds like a case for RxJava.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your code isn't safe.

First of all, for synchronization to be correct, all the access to the sharedstate must be synchronized, and not just the read access.

Second: synchronizing on a non-final field is wrong: since the field can change, one thread will acquire the lock on the old value and the second thread will then be able to enter the same synchronized section because the field has changed.

You don't have any atomicity problem to solve here: writing and reading a reference is guaranteed to be atomic. You have a visibility problem to solve though: nothing guarantees that the write made by the image reader thread (that writes the reference) will be visible by the robotic arm thread (that reads the reference).

So all you need is to make the field volatile, or to wrap it inside an AtomicReference:

```
private volatile BufferedImage lastImage;
```

or

```
private AtomicReference<BufferedImage> lastImageRef;

...
// in image reader
lastImageRef.set(theNewImage);

...
// in robotic arm
BufferedImage lastImage = lastImageRef.get();
```

If you were still willing to solve the visibility problem using synchronization, you would have to do something like:

```
static class LastImageHolder
    private BufferedImage lastImage;

    public synchronized BufferedImage get() {
        return lastImage;
    }

    public synchronized BufferedImage set(BufferedImage lastImage) {
        this.lastImage = lastImage;
    }
}

private LastImageHolder lastImageHolder = new LastImageHolder();
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize there was not an atomicity problem, as I assumed the different threads could be simultaneously reading and writing. If this is indeed true (writing and reading a reference is guaranteed to be atomic), then using the volatile keyword makes sense and is the easy solution. For fun I tried your `AtomicReference` solution, but it didn't work. The program just hung at the beginning, like there was a conflicting lock on the object or something. That happened before too with my `synchronized` blocks and why I took it off the reader thread.

Comment: Hard to comment and suprising, given that AtomicReference get() and set() simply consists in getting and setting a volatile field.

Answer (score -1):

Functionality like this can be done without locks. Here's a `OneOf`:

```
class OneOf<T> {

    volatile int which = 0;
    final T[] them;

    public OneOf(T[] them) {
        this.them = them;
    }

    public T get() {
        return get(0);
    }

    public T get(int skip) {
        return them[(which + skip) % them.length];
    }

    public void skip() {
        which += 1;
        which %= them.length;
    }
}
```

You can now use `get()` to get the current one, `get(1)` to peek at the following one. In your case your image reader will choose it's image using `get(1)` to begin filling the next image while your robot will read the image using `get()` to get the current one.

Comment: That is not thread-safe (skip), and I don't see how it answers the question. AFAIK, the goal is just to share a reference to a single value (lastImage) between threads. I also don't see how the image reader (which produces the image that must be read by the arm) would share the last image read with the arm.

Comment: @JBNizet - I think `skip` is thread-safe because of the `% them.length` in `get`. This is kind of double-buffering - it seemed appropriate for a reader that takes a while and another that just needs a most-recent.

Comment: `which += 1` isn't even thread-safe. If multiple threads call skip concurrently, you could miss increments.

Comment: @JBNizet - Acknowledged - but in the environment described (one image grabber and one robot) we do not have that problem.